# Algorithm - How many changes you have to make to get "impressive" number set

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

## The problem

An *impressive* set of numbers is the one, that contains *k* amount of *k* numbers for each number in the set.

For example `(5, 5, 5, 5, 5)`, `(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1)` and `(2, 2, 1)` are *impressive* sets.

`(3, 3, 2)` is not an *impressive* set, because there are two `3`s (should be three) and one `2` (should be two).

There is a list of `n` integers a<sub>i</sub> given so that (1 ≤ n ≤ 2000, 1 ≤ a<sub>i</sub> ≤ 2000).

Find the minimum amount of changes to get an *impressive* set. You can change one number at a time. The order doesn't matter. What's the final set doesn't matter.

## Examples

- **input: (3, 4, 3, 2, 1)** -> (3, 3, 3, 2, 1) -> (3, 3, 3, 2, 2) ==> **output: 2**
- **input: (5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)** -> (5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2) -> (5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2) ==> **output: 2**
- **input: (2, 2, 3, 3)** -> (2, 3, 3, 3) -> (1, 3, 3, 3) ==> **output: 2**

## Input/Output

The input to the function is a list. The output is an `int` denoting the minimum amount of changes.

## Sidenote

The program is supposed to be written in C++ with 64MB memory limit. Of course, **I am not asking for a solution, but for a hint on what to do algorithm-wise**.

Comment: The whole point of this exercise is the algorithm. Any hint *is* the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive formulation, where `g(i, j)` represents the least changes needed to achieve a set with cardinality `i`, considering numbers up to `j`. `O(n*n)` search space:

```js
function f(A){
  const n = A.length;
  const counts = new Array(n + 1).fill(0);
  
  for (let i of A)
    if (i <= n)
      counts[i]++;
      
  const h = {};

  function g(i, j){
    const key = `${i},${j}`;

    if (h.hasOwnProperty(key))
      return h[key];
    if (i == 0 || (i==j && j==counts[j]))
      return h[key] = 0;
    if (i < 0 || j < 1)
      return h[key] = Infinity;
      
    return h[key] = Math.min(
      // use j
      Math.max(j - counts[j], 0) + g(i - j, j - 1),
      // don't use j
      g(i, j - 1)
    )
  }
  return g(n, n);
}

for (i of [
  [2,2,3,3], // 2
  [3,4,3,2,1], // 2
  [5,5,5,5,5,5,5], // 2
  [1,2,3,4,5], // 3
  [1,1,2,3,4,5], // 3
  [5], // 1
  [3,2,1,1,1] // 3
]) console.log(JSON.stringify(i), f(i));

let largeRandomInput = [];
for (let i=0; i<2000; i++)
  largeRandomInput.push(~~(Math.random() * 2001));
  
const t0 = performance.now();
console.log(f(largeRandomInput));
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log((t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
```

Comment: Hey, this looks like a great alternative to what @Yola proposed. But it has the same problem as his algorithm: it doesn't scale for 2000 numbers. I've been running it for 10 minutes now for 2000 random int's and it just doesn't want to end. I think the complexity is too high, but I also don't think it's possible to do this with O(nlogn) or better. Your algorithm has a complexity of over O(n^2), which I don't think is a viable option. Still, great effort. I really appreciate it 

Comment: @DCzajkowski thank you for reading. The complexity of my algorithm is O(n^2) - there are only n*n relevant (i,j) combinations. The code is just an outline without https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization . A tabled version could possibly reduce calls to negative i's, too. I'm surprised you say Yola's code is not scaling to 2000. Is it not O(n^2)?

Comment: @גלעדברקן it isn't. The dp part is O(n^2), but the backtracking part apparently is not.

Comment: @DCzajkowski I added memoization and an example with 2000 random ints. The routine in the snippet takes 3~5 seconds in my browser to complete for 2000 numbers. I would think a tabled version in a lower-level language would be significantly faster.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Thanks, you've saved me this evening:)

Comment: @גלעד ברקן Incredible!

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it amounts to [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). First build the table, then extract one of the solutions for subset sum which has minimum *cost*.

E.g., for `1,2,3,4,5,5` we have `6` places in the array and five numbers `1,2,3,4,5`. And from these numbers, we need to find subsets which sum up to `6`. Then choose one which has the smallest number of changes required to build an impressive set.

The complexity of the algorithm is `O(n^2)`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

const short N = 2000;
short dp[N + 1][N];
const short NO = std::numeric_limits<short>::max();

class Impressive {
    short sum;
    std::array<short, N + 1> count = { { 0 } };
    const std::vector<short>& input;

    void SubsetsumDp()
    {
        for (short i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
            for (short j = 1; j <= sum; ++j) {
                short to_replace = i - count[i];
                if (i == j) dp[i][j] = to_replace;
                if (i > 0) {
                    if (dp[i - 1][j] != NO) {
                        dp[i][j] = std::min(dp[i][j], dp[i-1][j]);
                    }
                    if (j - i > 0) {
                        if (dp[i-1][j-i] != NO)
                        dp[i][j] = std::min(dp[i][j], (short)(dp[i - 1][j - i] + to_replace));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

public:
    Impressive(const std::vector<short>& v) : input(v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= N + 1; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= N; ++j) {
                dp[i][j] = NO;
            }
        }
    }

    short Solve()
    {
        for (auto i : input) if (count[i] < i) ++count[i];
        sum = (short)input.size();
        SubsetsumDp();
        return dp[input.size()][sum];
    }
};

void Test(const std::vector<short>& v)
{
    std::copy(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<short>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl << Impressive(v).Solve() << std::endl << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<short> input(2000);
    std::iota(input.begin(), input.end(), 1);
    Test(input);

    Test({ 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
    Test({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
    Test({ 5 });
    Test({ 3, 2, 1, 1, 1 });
    Test({ 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 });
    Test({ 4, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 });

    return 0;
}
```

> ...
>   1938
>
> 1 1 2 3 4 5
>   3
>
> 1 2 3 4 5
>   3
>
> 5
>   1
>
> 3 2 1 1 1
>   3
>
> 4 5 5 8 8 8 8 8
>   3
>
> 4 4 5 5 9 9 9 9 9
>   4

Comment: Why is 5 impossible? Can't we change it to 1 in one move?

Comment: @גלעדברקן ups, i thought we should use only provided numbers, but you are right. Probably i need to reconsider the whole algorithm.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Ok, now i consider all numbers from 1 to 2000. Thanks for pointing. Still, i'm not sure is that what was asked.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Argh, we need to build impressive **set**, not **number**, so `32332` counts.

Comment: This is impressive you solved this. But I am getting a bus error when executing. Do you know what may be the cause?

Comment: @DCzajkowski i updated the post with a possible solution.

Comment: I've compiled the code on Linux and except two missing headers it compiled. Segmentation fault persisted. It seems like there is a bug in the constructor. It should be smaller, not smaller or equal, as you are starting iterations with 0. After changing that it works perfectly. I'll verify if it works with larger arrays. You are amazing! Thank you 

Comment: @DCzajkowski Thanks! Yeh, that would be nice to test it more carefully then i did:)

Comment: Ok, so I've run it for 2000 random int's 1-2000, the program has been executing for an hour and there is still no answer. I don't think this is an optimal solution, unfortunately. I am extremely surprised by this exercise. I was teaching a 13-year-old who wants to attend an algorithmic competition and they expect those children to give an answer to this exercise in a very limited time. I find it ridiculous

Comment: @DCzajkowski yeh, I think I know what can be done. We don't need to consider all the numbers. I need to get back to my real job, but I hope I will update the answer before the weekend.

Comment: @DCzajkowski Woow, it works now. The idea which led me to this solution came in the first line of `Solve`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to answer this question: "For any `0 < k <= i <= n`, what is the minimum number of moves you need to stuff the smallest `i` elements into an impressive set whose largest element is no more than `k`?"

Your final answer is the answer to that question with `k = i = n`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of the "minimum change distance" problem -- how to change one sequence or set into another with the minimum quantity of insert/delete/modify operations.

The first thing you need to identify is the partitioning aspect: what sets of unique integers will sum to the size of your input set?  For each such combination, finding the minimal change distance is simple.

For your given cases above, you have the following possibilities:

- 4: {4}, {1, 3}
- 5: {5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}
- 7: {7}, {1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 4}

The partitioning problem is covered quite well in many places; I'll leave that research to you.  Note that "triangle" numbers (sum of the integers 1-n) are useful, as they describe the limit partitions.  For instance, `T(3) <= 7 < T(4)`, so the largest set of partitions for an impressive set of size 7 is 3: `{1, 2, 4}`

The quantity of changes is also simple, once you've determined the target set: count the matching elements and subtract from the set size.

That should be enough to move you toward a solution.

Comment: What is the algorithmic complexity of this solution?

Comment: I've made a Python script with this solution. It is a correct approach and gives correct answers, but generating sets of unique integers that add up to 2000 is very slow an yields lots of different answers.